# use "&" character in jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I want to use "&" character in jsf page but get error.

```
 <p:commandLink type="button" styleClass="close" aria-hidden="true"
                action="#{tages.removeText}" update="panel_topic" value="&time;">
     &times;
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tages._tar}" value="#{txt}"/>

 </p:commandLink>
```

following error :

```
Error Traced[line: 24] The entity "times" was referenced, but not declared.
```

how to use "&" character in jsf page ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `&amp;` instead of `&` in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use its decimal code: &#215